# How to increase max column/row of column/row splitter

Tags: sxa

Currently, I only can create 8 column/row for each column/row splitter.
Is there any way to increase the max # of column/row I can add in column/row splitter?

Comment: What version of SXA are you using?

Comment: @MichaelWest sxa 9.3

Comment: It's very possible that you could be over using the row splitter. Consider a layout where you need fewer rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage this from the config file, in `Sitecore.XA.Feature.PageStructure.config`. You can define the `maxSize` attribute on `splitterResizer` node. The default value is 8 here and that's why you can add only 8 maximum. See below image for reference -

[image]

It is recommended to create a patch config for updating any OOTB config properly or setting.