# Limit max number of composite components

Tags: sxa

Is there a way to limit the max number of composite items in an SXA composite component like Carousel? For example the carousel has no more then 8 slides.
It sounds like SXA does not have anything built in and I'd need to implement some sort of validation. If that is the case can anyone share an example of how to achieve that?

This is on SXA 10.2

Comment: The Splitters have a configuration for that. Perhaps you can see if something similar exists for Carousel. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25341/how-to-increase-max-column-row-of-column-row-splitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding the validation through `OnItemCreated` event. Where you can specify your template name (for example `Carousel`) and if its child items exceed the limit then you can show the message and delete the item. The code will look like this.

```
public void OnItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var createdArgs = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as ItemCreatedEventArgs;

    if (createdArgs != null)
    {
        if (createdArgs.Item != null)
        {
            var item = createdArgs.Item;

            if (item.Parent != null && 
                item.Parent.TemplateName == "carousel" &&
                item.Parent.Children.Count() > 8)
            {
                SheerResponse.Alert(
                    String.Format("Sorry, you cannot add more than 8 slides to {0}.",
                                      item.Parent.Name), new string[0]);
               
               // write here your logic to delete the item. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works when you create the item from the `content editor` and `experience editor`.

Once you are done with your method then register it using a patch config like this.

```
<event name="item:created">
    <handler type="MyProject.Sc.Extensions.Events.ItemCreatedEvent, MyProject.Sc.Extensions" method="OnItemCreated" />
</event>
```

It will look like this.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected I had to implement that custom event if SXA didn't have any sort of built in validation